# IIS backup using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, server

I am trying to take a backup of my IIS websites using msdeploy.
Following is the command I use manually:
.\msdeploy.exe '-verb:sync' '-source:metakey=lm/w3svc/2' '-dest:package=C:\iis_backups\site2.zip,encryptPassword=xyz' > C:\iis_ba.\ckups\site2.log

But how can I use the for\foreach to get it done for all sites in one go?

Answer (score 0):

I would use double quotes and put the Id within it:

```
get-website|foreach-object $_.ID { 
$p=$_id;
.\msdeploy.exe '-verb:sync' "-source:metakey=lm/w3svc/$p" "-dest:package=C:\iis_backups\$p.zip,encryptPassword=xyz" > "C:\iis_backups\$p.log"}
```

Comment: Ok,tried this,but I think we have a problem with naming the file here.Its creating a backup file named '$p' instead of an ID of a site.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it. Just give it another try.

Comment: No error, but it is creating blank named folders and that too not the same number as that of sites.